# Unable to find "Subdivide Smooth" option in blender 2.8

Tags: subdivision-surface

This question is exactly the question I'm asking:
[Model appears to have visible polygons rather than being smooth?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114642/model-appears-to-have-visible-polygons-rather-than-being-smooth)

I've read it but I can't find the subdivide smooth option even after doing the operator search. I'm using 2.8 and their using an older version in that post so I'm guessing thats why. Is there a subdivide smooth option in 2.8? If not, is there another way to get my mesh as smooth as Hokiroya's? He seems to be using a subdivision surface modifier and I tried to match my settings to his but no luck. Is the smooth shading option a long term solution? I'm planning on rigging this model and after spending a lot of time on a another failed model I want to make sure I know what I'm doing before I start sculpting.

Mine:[image]

Hokiroya's (obviously lol):
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The 'Subdivide Smooth' option in previous versions of Blender simply applied a Subdivide operation with the Smooth parameter set to 1.0 - the Smooth parameter is available in the Tool properties 'Redo' panel available in the left-hand panel.

It seems that in Blender 2.8 the menus have been pruned to remove unnecessary options - instead, you can adjust the 'Smoothness' by simply opening the tool properties (the floating Subdivide panel at the bottom-left) and varying Smoothness :

[image: Subdivide Smooth]

However, I don't think that is your complete solution - in your case, possibly you also need to set the mesh itself to 'Smooth' shading. At 2.8, this is available in the Object menu as 'Shade Smooth' :

[image: smooth shading]

Comment: Thanks :D it works well. I actually like this better than the subdivision surface modifier because it doesn't change the shape of the object. What's the difference between using the modifier and doing it this way?

Comment: @NaomiYokoo The modifier doesn't actually change the underlying geometry (until you 'Apply' it) so it's non-destructive and you can remove or disable the modifier whenever you like to revert to the previously (unsubdivided) geometry, whereas using the Subdivide in Edit mode does directly affect the mesh. If the reason for the subdivision is to add geometry to use in sculpting (in which case you've have to 'apply' the modifier anyway) then using the Edit mode subdivide (with smooth parameter) is more versatile.